# iphone access orkut api

Tags: iphone

Does anybody know a code sample for accessing the orkut API thought the iPhone SDK? I only found this java version http://code.google.com/p/orkut-os-client/ that's no good for me.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK - API for orkut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728331/iphone-sdk-api-for-orkut)

Answer (score 3):

There is not a iOS version of the orkut client. Google provided just the Java client, and the community built the PHP, QT and .NET clients by reverse engeneering.