# Orkut API for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Does Orkut have any API to post messages from iPhone?
I am developing an app for iPhone and want the ability to post also to Orkut.
I have found APIs from Facebook and Twitter but not for Orkut.

Comment: if there is any other way like edit url or something like that to quickly add post to orkut. this will help also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone access orkut api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061909/iphone-access-orkut-api)

Answer (score 3):

There is not a iOS version of the orkut client. Google provided just the [Java client](http://code.google.com/p/orkut-os-client/), and the community built the PHP, QT and .NET clients by reverse engeneering.