# iPhone SDK - API for orkut

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have worked in retrieving the contacts information from Google contacts in iPhone using gData library. Similarly I gonna work with Orkut. Is there any library available for Orkut like gData? If so, provide me the link. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For orkut we have the orkut client.

Unfortunatly there is not a iOS version of the orkut client, and there is not docs for the API calls as gData have. Google provided just the [Java client](http://code.google.com/p/orkut-os-client/), and the community built the PHP, QT and .NET clients by reverse engeneering.